# Writing cout-formated data to printf

Tags: android, c++, windows, logging, io

I am doing logging for an cross-platform application, and I'm trying to understand how I should do when it comes to for example Android, in which the default logging system in C++ uses a printf-formated function. However I want to use the '<<' operator to log easily, for example

```
std::string myName = Johan;
int myID = 1;
mLogger << "Hello my name is: " << myName << " and my ID is: " << myID;
```

Now how would one go about converting this to a printf-friendly format? Is there an easy way to do this?

**EDIT**: mLogger is an output-stream. I am to overload the '<<' operator and try to somehow built a correctly-formated string from its input to use for printf. Is that clearer?

Comment: What's `mLogger`? A stringstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a string stream to format the message:

```
std::ostringstream msg;
std::string myName = "Johan";
int myID = 1;

msg << "Hello my name is " << myName << " and my ID is: " << myId;
```

Passing the string to `printf` is then rather simple:

```
printf("%s", msg.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf("Hello my name is: %s and my ID is: %d", myName.c_str(), myId);`

Comment: I know the format, I mean, how do I go about building it based on the input from '<<'?

Comment: If that is your goal, consider @jrok 's answer